A movie with an orphan called Astrid
So this movie is about a girl whose mother is in prison for killing her husband and Astrid (the girl) is an orphan who's been in 3 diffrent foster homes.
The first foster home she's been, she's been shot,
The second one, [someone?] killed herself,
And in the third foster home, she became some sort of emo or something (black hair, lots of makeup, smoking, drinking).

Just as a note, if you're looking to learn to fish so to speak, if you know a character name, you can often Google something like "Character named Astrid" and get a list like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrid As you can see, the book White Oleander is on this list. It won't always work, but it might help in future.

It's called White Oleander from 2002 with Alison Lohman, Michelle Pfeiffer and Renée Zellweger, among others.

A teenager [Astrid] journeys through a series of foster homes after her mother goes to prison for committing a crime of passion. 

Here's the trailer:



